# Five girls and eleven boys are to be lined up in a row such that... Where is my mistake?

Tags: combinatorics

> Five girls and eleven boys are to be lined up in a row such that from
>   left to right, the girls are in the order $g_1g_2g_3g_4g_5$. In how
>   many ways can this be done if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are to be separated by
>   atleast 3 boys, and there is at most one boy between $g_4$ and $g_5$.

First take a look at this which shows the number of ways to put $r$ distinct objects into $n$ distinct boxes such that order matters: If you are too lazy to read it, it basically says that the number of ways to put $r$ distinct objects into $n$ distinct boxes such that the order in the boxes matters is given by $P^{n+r-1}_{r}$[image]

The whole idea is to count the arrangements where there is an arbitrary number of boys between $g_1$ and $g_2$ and atmost one between $g_4$ and $g_5$ and then subract the number of arrangements where there are less than $3$ boys between $g_1$ and $g_2$ (atmost one between $g_4$ and $g_5$).

First count the arrangements where there is an arbitrary number of boys between $g_1$ and $g_2$ and atmost one between $g_4$ and $g_5$. If you arrange the girls as $\_g_1\_g_2\_g_3\_g_4g_5\_$, then the dashes can be treated as boxes where to put the boys. Observe that there is no dash between $g_4$ and $g_5$. Case 1: there is no object between $g_4$ and $g_5$. There are $P^{15}_{5}$ such arrangements. Case 2: There is one object between $g_4$ and $g_5$. There are $11\times P^{14}_{5}$ such arrangements. Thus, the total is $3003000$.

Now, count the number of permutations where there are less than $3$ boys between $g_1$ and $g_2$. Case 1: $0$ objects between them. If there is no object between $g_4$ and $g_5$ you have $P^{14}_{4}$ and if there is you have $11\times P^{13}_{4}$, so in this case there are $212784$ arrangements. In the same manner for the cases where there are $1$ and $2$ objects between $g_1$ and $g_2$ you get, respectively, the values $11\times P^{13}_{4} + 11\times 10\times P^{12}_{4} = 1,519,684$ and $2\times {11\choose2}\times P^{12}_4 + 2\times{11\choose2}\times 9\times P^{11}_{4} = 3,920,400$ which alone is larger than $3003000$, so there is obviously a mistake.

I know there are more elegant approaches to this (share them if you like), but the main question is where is the mistake in the current approach?

Comment: I think you may be getting your $r$ and $n$ mixed up , surely your case #1 should be $P^{15}_{11}$ instead of $P^{15}_5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you claim in your Case 1 that there are $P^{15}_5$ arrangements where the girls are in the given order and $g_4$ is right next to $g_5$. The quantity $P^{15}_5$ is the number of ways to choose an ordered subset of $5$ from a set of $15$, and that doesn't seem to apply here-- you know the five girls will be in the given order.

The way I understand it, you have a line with $15$ spaces, and you want to choose $4$ of those spaces to put your girls (since $g_4$ and $g_5$ come together as a package.) Then the remaining $11$ spaces will be filled as a permutation of the boys. So you have $\binom{15}{4} \cdot 11!$ possible arrangements under those conditions. Then in the other case, pick a boy to go between $g_4$ and $g_5$. Then there are really ony $14$ spaces in the line, so you have $\binom{14}{4}$ choices of spaces to put the girls, and the boys fill the remaining spaces as a permutation again, so Case 2 yields $11 \cdot \binom{14}{4} \cdot 10! = \binom{14}{4} \cdot 11!$.

To solve the problem, first fix three boys to go directly in front of $g_1$ in a given order. There are $\frac{11!}{8!} = 990$ ways to do so. Then use a similar argument as above: In one case, $\binom{12}{4}$ ways to choose places for the girls (with their attachments), and $8!$ ways to fill the remaining places. In the other case, $\binom{11}{4}$ choices of places for girls, times $8!$. The total is $990 \cdot 8! \cdot (\binom{12}{4} + \binom{11}{4})$.

This can be simplified nicely: $990 \cdot 8! = 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8! = 11!$, and $\binom{12}{4} = 495$ and $\binom{11}{4} = 330$, so the final answer is $825 \cdot 11!$.

Comment: Before completly reading your answer let me just answer the first question. The reason why there are $P^{15}_{5}$ is because you have 5 boxes and 11 boys to put in those boxes and by the theorem shown in the picture this can be done in $P^{15}_{5}$

Comment: Aha! Then the theorem says that you should have $P^{15}_{11}$, because you have $11$ objects that you're trying to place. I should double-check but I think that agrees with my answer.

Comment: Indeed it does: $\binom{15}{4} \cdot 11! = \frac{15!}{4! \cdot 11!} \cdot 11! = \frac{15!}{4!}$.

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect as the answer is $11!\times 825$. But you are right on my mistake on the formula

Comment: My answer simplifies to that. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I tried to directly calculate the your result and must have missed something, but when you choose the 3 boys to go directly in front of $g_1$ arent there ${11\choose 3}\times 6$ ways. I mean ${11\choose 3}$ ways to choose them and then 3! ways to arrange them?

Comment: Correct, and equal to what I wrote. I put $\frac{11!}{8!}$, which is $P^{11}_{3}$. It looks like you took an unordered group $C^{11}_{3} = \frac{11!}{3! \cdot 8!}$, and multiplied by the number of ways to order them ($3!$). Combinatorics problems tend to have lots of different ways to the solution.

Comment: Well, you have made an error, as $P^{11}_3 = 990$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24768/discussion-between-zach-gershkoff-and--).

Answer (score 0):

From context I assume $P_i^j = \frac{j!}{(i-1)!}$, but then I get different numbers than you:
$$P_5^{15}+11P_5^{14} = 94443148800$$
and
$$P_4^{14} + 11P_4^{13} = 25945920000$$
$$11P_4^{13} + 11\cdot10\cdot P_4^{12} = 20197900800$$
$$11\cdot 10\cdot P_4^{12} + 11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot P_3^{11} = 15367968000$$
and, at least, the second group sums to less than the first.

Comment: I am sorry, $P^j_i = \frac{j!}{(j-i)!}$. I thought this was common notation for permutation.

Comment: see this http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php

Comment: It's common in some contexts. Personally, I just prefer to write out what it means because I find it confusing to have to subtract by $i$.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев In that case what you have in your question in incorrect: $n(n+1)\ldots(n+r-1) = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!}$, not $P_n^{n+r-1}$.

Comment: If you let $k = (n+r-1)$ then $n(n-1)(n-2)...(n+r-1) = k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-r+1) = P^{k}_{r} = P^{n+r-1}_{r}$

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Right, but that's not what you've done in your question. In your question the subscripts are the number of boxes $n$, not the number of boys $r$.

Comment: I know, that has been pointed out twice already. This is my mistake. Hold on, I will edit my question after reading the posted answers.

Comment: Well, that is *the* mistake... once you fix it you get the right answer and there is nothing left to ask ;)