# Number of arrangements of 5 girls and 11 boys

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q: Five girls and eleven boys are to be lined up in a row such that from left to right, the girls are in the order: $G_1, G_2, G_3, G_4, G_5$. In how many ways can this be done if $G_1$ and $G_2$ must be separated by at least 3 boys, and there is at most one boy between $G_4$ and $G_5$?

A: 11!$\cdot$825

Apart from the solution from [Five girls and eleven boys are to be lined up in a row such that... Where is my mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323125/five-girls-and-eleven-boys-are-to-be-lined-up-in-a-row-such-that-where-is-my) , is there an alternative approach via finding the number of integer solutions to the equation: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 11$ for example?

Here's my thought process. I viewed each girl $G_i$ as a "+" operator:

$$ G_1 \quad G_2 \quad G_3 \quad G_4 \quad G_5 $$

such that each gap between the $G_i$'s has a $x_i$, such that we have

$$ x_1  + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 11$$

where 11 is the number of boys, and $x_i \geq 0$ for i $\in$ $\{1,3,4,5,6\}$, $x_2 \geq 3$, $x_5 \leq1$.

How do I go about this approach? I got stuck after reaching the last step stated above.

Comment: Instead of looking at $x_2 \geq 3$ you could just take away 3 boys and insert them later between them, giving you the equation $x_1+ \ldots+x_6=8$ and $x_2 \geq 0$. For $x_4$ I would do 2 cases. One with a boy in between and one without. Now you should have a form you can solve.

Comment: Alrights I'll work on it!

Comment: @TravisJ ah yes it is. Sorry I'll edit it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint that $x_2\geq 3$ is easy to solve.  Just re-write your equation like: $x_1 + (3+x_2) + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 11$ (now $x_2\geq 0$) and you can simplify.  Just think of starting off by forcing at least 3 boys into that position (you now have 8 left to work with).

The constraint that $x_4\leq 1$ is less easy.  Personally, I'd split this into cases: what happens when $x_4=0$? and what happens when $x_4=1$.  It is easy in this case because there are only two options.  It would be more painful if the constraint were something like $x_4\leq M$ where $M$ is a big number (presumably in the case where you had more than 11 boys).

Comment: Hmm.. Do you mean splitting into cases where $x_4 \geq 0$ and $x_4 \geq 1$ such that I can find the number of possibilites for the interval $0 \leq x \leq 1$ ?

Comment: @Stoner, your constraint was that $x_4\leq 1$... that leaves only two options.  Either $x_4=0$ or $x_4=1$.  If, for example, $x_4=0$ then your equation is $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_5+x_6=8$ (already removed the 3 boys) and each variable is $\geq 0$.

Comment: Similarly, if $x_4=1$ then you have $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_5+x_6=7$ (removed 3 boys as before plus the 1 in position 4).

Comment: Alrights going by your suggestion, I have the number of integer solutions for $x_4 = 0$ to be ${12 \choose 8}$ and $x_4 = 1$ to be ${11 \choose 8}$. Is that correct? If it is, do I add them up?

Comment: @Stoner, for the $x_4=0$ case you do have $\binom{12}{8}=\binom{12}{4}$, but for the $x_4=1$ case you have $\binom{11}{7}=\binom{11}{4}$.  Then, yes, you add them.

Comment: Oh gosh what a careless mistake I made on $x_4 = 1$.. Awesome! As for the $11!$ am I right to say that its just for arranging the 11 boys?

Comment: @Stoner, yes you multiply by $11!$ (if you assume that the boys are distinguishable... i.e. the order of the boys is important).  If the boys are storm troopers (i.e. clones, or indistinguishable from each other) then you wouldn't need to multiply by the $11!$.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thanks for the clarification and help! :)